# CUDA.jl: What is the most time-efficient way of copying data from CuArrays?

Tags: performance, cuda, julia, gpu

I'm working on some code to solve the restricted (where the gravitational field is analytically solved for) n-body problem, involving the Sun, Jupiter and many asteroids/rockets in a 2D solar system. Using CUDA.jl, I parallelised the propagation of my asteroids using CUDA.jl's higher-order abstractions. My problem is that after each time step I want to save the X and Y positions of all my asteroids by putting them in 2 2D arrays (one for X and one for Y), such that the first row of the arrays are the initial X and Y positions of my asteroids, and the second row shows their positions after one time step, etc. I found that copying over this data and storing it was the slowest part of my program. Is there an easy way to speed this up?

This is my current code.

```
function MassCoordsCircle(rotation::AbstractFloat,radius::AbstractFloat)
    return radius*cos(rotation),radius*sin(rotation)

end

function FindForcesArr(rocketCoord::AbstractArray,mass1Coord::AbstractFloat,mass2Coord::AbstractFloat,rocketOtherCoord::AbstractArray,mass1OtherCoord::AbstractFloat,mass2OtherCoord::AbstractFloat,mass1::AbstractFloat,mass2::AbstractFloat,G::AbstractFloat)
    return -G*mass1*(rocketCoord.-mass1Coord) ./ sqrt.((rocketCoord.-mass1Coord) .^ 2 .+ (rocketOtherCoord.-mass1OtherCoord) .^2 ) .^ 3 .- G*mass2*(rocketCoord.-mass2Coord) ./ sqrt.((rocketCoord.-mass2Coord) .^ 2 .+ (rocketOtherCoord.-mass2OtherCoord) .^ 2) .^3

end

function TaylorArr(x::AbstractArray,y::AbstractArray,vx::AbstractArray,vy::AbstractArray,mass1::AbstractFloat,mass2::AbstractFloat,dMass1::AbstractFloat,dMass2::AbstractFloat,G::AbstractFloat,mass1Rotation::AbstractFloat,mass2Rotation::AbstractFloat,period::AbstractFloat,dt::AbstractFloat)
    mass1x,mass1y=MassCoords(mass1Rotation,dMass1)
    mass2x,mass2y=MassCoords(mass2Rotation,dMass2)
    ax=FindForcesArr(x,mass1x,mass2x,y,mass1y,mass2y,mass1,mass2,G)
    ay=FindForcesArr(y,mass1y,mass2y,x,mass1x,mass2x,mass1,mass2,G)
    return x .+ dt .* vx .+ dt^2/2 .* ax,y .+ dt.*vy .+ dt^2/2 .* ay,vx .+ dt .* ax,vy .+ dt .* ay
    
end

using CUDA
using Plots
using PyPlot
using PyCall
np=pyimport("numpy")

G=6.6726e-11
#Mass of Sun
mass1=1.989e30
#Mass of Jupiter
mass2=1.898e27
#Sun-Jupiter distance
d_mass1_mass2=7.7834082e11
timeStep=100000.0
numberParticles=2000

d_COM_mass1=d_mass1_mass2*mass2/(mass1+mass2)
d_COM_mass2=d_mass1_mass2*mass1/(mass1+mass2)
MassCoords=MassCoordsCircle
PropagateParticle=TaylorArr

period=sqrt(4*pi^2/(G*(mass1+mass2))*d_mass1_mass2^3)


steps=trunc(Int64,div(period,timeStep)+1)
mass1xHistory=zeros(steps)
mass1yHistory=zeros(steps)
mass2xHistory=zeros(steps)
mass2yHistory=zeros(steps)

particleXs=CUDA.randn(Float64,numberParticles).*1e12
particleYs=CUDA.randn(Float64,numberParticles).*1e12
particleVXs=CUDA.randn(Float64,numberParticles).*15000
particleVYs=CUDA.randn(Float64,numberParticles).*15000

particleXHistories=Array{Float64}(undef,steps,numberParticles)
particleYHistories=Array{Float64}(undef,steps,numberParticles)

time=0
step=1
while step<=steps
    #Sun is 180 degrees out of sync with Jupiter.
    mass1Rotation=time/period*2*pi+pi
    mass2Rotation=time/period*2*pi
    mass1x,mass1y=MassCoords(mass1Rotation,d_COM_mass1)
    mass2x,mass2y=MassCoords(mass2Rotation,d_COM_mass2)

    mass1xHistory[step]=mass1x
    mass1yHistory[step]=mass1y
    mass2xHistory[step]=mass2x
    mass2yHistory[step]=mass2y

    particleXsRAM=Array(particleXs)
    particleYsRAM=Array(particleYs)
    for count in 1:numberParticles
        particleXHistories[step,count]=particleXsRAM[count]
        particleYHistories[step,count]=particleYsRAM[count]

    end

    particleXs,particleYs,particleVXs,particleVYs=PropagateParticle(particleXs,particleYs,particleVXs,particleVYs,mass1,mass2,d_COM_mass1,d_COM_mass2,G,mass1Rotation,mass2Rotation,period,timeStep)

    time=time+timeStep
    step=step+1
        
end

plt.figure(1,figsize=[7,7])
plt.plot(mass1xHistory,mass1yHistory)
plt.plot(mass2xHistory,mass2yHistory)
plt.plot(np.array(particleXHistories),np.array(particleYHistories))
plt.xlim([-9e11,9e11])
plt.ylim([-9e11,9e11])
plt.show()
```

The asteroids are given random starting locations and velocities. I used matplotlib over Plots because it was significantly faster when generating the first graph.

I apologise for the big block of code; I wanted to give a working example. In particular though, I want to draw your attention to the block from the line `particleXsRAM=Array(particleXs)` to the end of the `for` loop.

```
particleXsRAM=Array(particleXs)
particleYsRAM=Array(particleYs)
for count in 1:numberParticles
    particleXHistories[step,count]=particleXsRAM[count]
    particleYHistories[step,count]=particleYsRAM[count]

end
```

`particleXs` and `particleYs` are CuArrays.

This is the part where I am saving the data after each time-step, and I am slightly concerned about the performance of this block. Currently the fastest way I have found to save the data is by translating the CuArray into a normal Julia array, and putting that into a Julia 2D array element by element. However, I was wondering if there was a way to parallelise this using the higher-order abstractions?

So far, I've also tried to create a 2D CuArray for each asteroid's X and Ys, and copying the data over element by element, but this seemed to be completed by the CPU instead of the GPU. I've also tried to create an array of CuArrays, and, while this executed quickly, I wasn't able to make it plot in an amount of time that made the trade-off worth it.

This code does provide a performance boost over my non-parallelised code, but not as much as I had hoped.

Comment: Keep in mind that Julia arrays are column major. Consider carefully how to organize your data layout. For example, `particleXHistories[:, step]=particleXs` would be more efficient.

Comment: and you cannot overestimate how important the comment of @DNF is for efficiency! This is the first thing to try in your code!

Comment: If you have an answer, add it as an answer. Don't edit a solution into your question

Answer (score 1):

I thought I had already tried this, but it turns out that Julia's normal array syntax works. You can just initialise two 2D CuArrays before the loop:

```
particleXHistories=CuArray{Float64}(undef,steps,numberParticles)
particleYHistories=CuArray{Float64}(undef,steps,numberParticles)
```

and then inside the loop update them like so:

```
particleXHistories[step,:]=particleXs
particleYHistories[step,:]=particleYs
```

This definitely speeds up the propagation part of my program. It does slow down the plotting part as the resulting data still needs to be turned into a normal Julia array using `Array(particleXHistories)` for X and Y but from my quick preliminary tests I think it's an overall speed increase.